# How to get the text of a 404 error page

Tags: vb.net, html

I'm trying to make an application which gets the word count and data size of a web page given its URL.  A am able to get the data for the page when the page exists, such as this URL:

https://twitter.com/StarPartyBandUK

But I'm unable to get the data for the 404 error page which is displayed when the URL leads to a page which does not exist, such as this link:

https://twitter.com/StarPartyBandUK2

The first url is an example of a twitter profile, however the second url is a non-existent page which returns the user with a page designated for 404 errors.  How can I get the data for the 404 error that gets displayed when you click on that second link?

Comment: What part of this task are you having trouble with?

Comment: The most notable flaw is when program tries to return the file size of a page that doesn't exist, like the second link I posted as the example above. Visual Basic returns a 404 error. Of course it's a page that's not found, but a 404 page is generated, and this page I need to find the file size... I know that there's a way around this 404 error to get the file size of this page. This site that retrieves page file sizes, even those like the second link above: http://www.searchenginegenie.com/tools/getPageSize.php

Comment: Ah, ok.  That makes more sense and makes for a good question.  I updated your question to better reflect your actual specific problem and changed my vote.

Answer (score 0):

You can use System.Net.WebClient.DownloadString for that. Then count the characters and words in the string.